# Rake on jenkins runs without errors but abort in the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, rake, watir

In our company we are using ruby + watir for our test automation on a jenkins. We use the rake command to execute these tests and they are passing without an error but the rake always abort.

Here the error:

```
Finished in 154.48291s
22 tests, 109 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Writing XML reports to /<path>/Tests/results
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib" -I"/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib" "/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "<path>/test1.rb" "<path>/test2.rb" "<path>/test3.rb" "<path>/test4.rb" ]
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/testtask.rb:130:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `call'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `sh'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:105:in `ruby'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/testtask.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:59:in `verbose'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/testtask.rb:111:in `block in define'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `call'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:237:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:212:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => test
```

Can someone help me to understand what does that mean and what I can do? Google wasn't helpfull for me.

Comment: It looks like the failure is in the XML generation, not the tests themselves. Does the folder `/<path>/Tests/` (with a capital T??!!) exist? - Maybe you just needed a lower-case T, or a step to create the folder, or a `.keep` file in the folder, so it's persisted in source control.

Comment: So in summary, my **BEST GUESS**, given you haven't actually shown what's generating the XML report above, is that you've configured Jenkins using [something like this](https://github.com/ci-reporter/ci_reporter#jenkins-setup), but entered a non-existent folder (e.g. `Tests` instead of `test`).